# What is the error in syntax for my code? sql java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I've been staring at my code forever trying to figure out the syntax error that's happening:

> ERROR: table creation is interrupted by java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    getConnection();

    boolean quit = false;
    while (!quit) {
        System.out.println("Select from the following options: \n" + "1) Create Table \n" + "2) Search Table \n"
                + "3) Quit \n" + "> ");
        int choice = kbd.nextInt();
        if (choice == 1) {

            System.out.println("Name your table: ");
            String tableName = kbd.nextLine();

            kbd.nextLine();

            System.out.println("How many columns would you like? ");
            int numColumns = kbd.nextInt();
            String[] columnTypes = new String[numColumns];
            String columnSpec = "";
            kbd.nextLine();
            String[] types = { "VARCHAR(100)", "INT", "decimal(3,2)" };
            int typeChoice;
            for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
                System.out.printf(
                        "Select the type for column %d: \n" + "1)VarChar\n" + "2)Integer\n" + "3)Decimal\n > ",
                        i + 1);

                typeChoice = kbd.nextInt();

                kbd.nextLine();

                System.out.printf("Enter Column %d's name: ", i + 1);
                String columnsName = kbd.nextLine();

                if (typeChoice == 1) {
                    columnSpec += columnCreator(columnsName, types[0]);
                    columnTypes[i] = types[0];
                } else if (typeChoice == 2) {
                    columnSpec += columnCreator(columnsName, types[1]);
                    columnTypes[i] = types[1];
                } else {
                    columnSpec += columnCreator(columnsName, types[2]);
                    columnTypes[i] = types[2];
                }

            }
            columnSpec = columnSpec.substring(0, columnSpec.length() - 2);

            System.out.println(columnSpec);
            Trans.create(tableName, columnSpec);
            quit = true;
        }
    }
}

public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    try {
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        System.out.println("\n=> loading driver:");
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        System.out.println("OK");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Walkthrough?useSSL=false";

        System.out.println("\n=> connecting:");
        DriverManager.getConnection(url, Trans.user, Trans.password);
        System.out.println("OK");
    } catch (Exception x) {
        System.err.println(x);
    }
    return null;
}

public static String columnCreator(String name, String type) {
    return name + " " + type + ", ";
}
```

**Trans Class:**

```
public class Trans {
    static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Walkthrough?useSSL=false";
    static String user = "root";
    static String password = "password";

    public static void create(String table, String values) {
        // need to ensure not existing.
        // values = "id VARCHAR(6), quiz INT, avg decimal(3,2)";
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            Connection cx = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            Statement st = cx.createStatement();
            String sql_drop = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table;
            st.executeUpdate(sql_drop);

            String sql_create = "CREATE TABLE " + table + '(' + values + ')';

            st.executeUpdate(sql_create);
            System.out.println("Table has been created");
        } catch (Exception x) {
            System.err.println("table creation is interrupted by " + x);
        }
    }
}
```

The print out of columnSpec:

```
col1 VARCHAR(100), col2 VARCHAR(100), col3 VARCHAR(100)
```

Print out of tableName:

```
nameoftable
```

Any insight or help would be be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What library are you using to access your database? What is the type of `trans`? What does your `columnSpec` string contain? Where is `columnCreator()`?

Comment: please show the result of `System.out.println(columnSpec);`

Comment: re: *I've been staring at my code forever* - that's the wrong way to go about it.  Since the error is in the SQL syntax, you need to know what's in the tableName and columnSpec values. As suggested: **print them out**.

Comment: thanks for your comments guys, I edited the code above to give you a better idea.

Comment: Geia sou Dimitra! Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), so that you can improve your answer. But, to save you some time, here are some pointers: 1) Don't dump all of your code in the post and expect someone to run and debug it for you. Read the error message, understand it and then post only the **relevant** code. 2)Explain what you tried but failed, what tools you used, etc. I recommend IntelliJ for debugging and especially for an IDE.

Comment: You're right, so sorry! I don't post much, I will edit this post very soon and make it better. Will do so from now on as well. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
String sql_create = "CREATE TABLE " + table + '(' + values + ')';
```

with

```
String sql_create = "CREATE TABLE " + table + " (" + values + ")";
```

I suggest you debug/print the value of `sql_create` before calling `st.executeUpdate(sql_create);`. It should print like:

```
CREATE TABLE nameoftable (col1 VARCHAR(100), col2 VARCHAR(100), col3 VARCHAR(100))
```

**Update:** I also see two calls of `nextLine()`, one after the other.

```
System.out.println("Name your table: ");
String tableName = kbd.nextLine();
kbd.nextLine();
```

Why do you need the second call? Remove the second line, `kbd.nextLine();`.

Not just this, why do you need `kbd.nextLine();` again after `String columnSpec = "";`?

```
String columnSpec = "";
kbd.nextLine();
```

and the following `kbd.nextLine();` after `typeChoice = kbd.nextInt();`?

```
typeChoice = kbd.nextInt();
kbd.nextLine();
```

Remove all these unnecessary calls of `kbd.nextLine();`.

Comment: thank you, I notice that my tableName isn't getting stored in the String. Only shows "". Not sure why...

Comment: It actually doesn't reach that part to create sql_create. In main, where it says String tableName = kbd.nextLine(); I noticed when I debug past it after giving it a name, it still show tableName = ""; Never gets saved in String

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate it!